# Why isn't grep working with iostat?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep

I'm trying to collect some disk usage statistics as specified [here](https://exchange.nagios.org/components/com_mtree/attachment.php?link_id=1750&cf_id=29), for using with [this](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/System-Metrics/Storage-Subsystem/Iostat--2D-check_tps/details)  nagios plugin

In short it should get the tps for the second lecture in the output comming from iostat like this:

```
/usr/bin/iostat -d /dev/vda -t 1 | grep -n vda | grep 9:vda | awk -F" " '{print $2;}'
```

The problem is that the second `grep` wont collect anything.

I tried something similar with `find` that does the same thing, and seems to work though

```
find | grep -n ./home | grep 9:./home
```

A shorter version of the command that reproduces the issue is like so

```
iostat -d /dev/vda -t 1 | grep -n vda | grep 9:vda
```

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with grep 2.25

```
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.25
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
```

Comment: [Why no output is shown when using grep twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427483/why-no-output-is-shown-when-using-grep-twice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Alvin Lang](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094993/why-isnt-grep-working-with-iostat#comment1803165_1094993) gave the reason why [the second grep doesn't output anything quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427483/why-no-output-is-shown-when-using-grep-twice). That said, if you just want the second match, you can tell `grep` to quit after the second match (`-m2`) and take the last line:

```
$ iostat -d /dev/vda -t 1 | grep -n vda -m2 | awk 'END {print $2}'
19.00
```

Or even do the entire thing (matching and counting) in awk:

```
iostat -d /dev/vda -t 1 | awk '/vda/ && ++count == 2 {print $2; exit}'
```

(The `find` command  worked better likely because it filled grep's buffers far faster than iostat could. The sheer volume of output from `find` is not something `iostat` can hope to match.)